# Android Retrofit start another request from success method

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I'm using retrofit to add a task.

```
private void addTask(Map<String, String> map) {

    ApiClient.getPptApiClient().addTask(map, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            Log.d("TAG", "add task success");
            downloadTasks(id)

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            Log.d("TAG", "add task failed");
        }
    });
}
```

after add task succes i want to refresh my list, and for that i have method below:

```
private void downloadTasks(int id) {
    ApiClient.getPptApiClient().getTasks(id, new Callback<ArrayList<TaskModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(ArrayList<TaskModel> taskModels, Response response) {
            Log.d("TAG", "download task success");
            taskAdapter.clear();
            taskAdapter.addAll(taskModels);
            lvTasks.setAdapter(taskAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            Log.e("TAG", "download task failed");

        }
    });
}
```

My problem is : downloadTask is never called.
Can you explain why?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `downloadTasks(id)`. I'm pretty sure that's just a typo. If the `success()` method is called, then `downloadTasks()` will be called as well. Are you sure `success` is being called?

Comment: Ty for fast response.. i solved my problem. success was not called because response from server is not a string. I called downloadTask from failure and it works. Now i must do something with that response.